# ASP show panel if radiobutton is clicked

Tags: asp.net

i want to show the panel 'keuze' if i click one of the radio buttons.
This is the code i have sofar, i am already trying over a hour to get it working. But i really cant find the solution so if someone could help i would really appreciate that.

```
   <div id="object" style="position:absolute; top:300px;">
        <label>Kies een object:</label>
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblObject" runat="server" Height="52px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblObject_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="rblVloer">Vloer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="rblKamer">Kamer</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="keuze" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top:400px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Maak je keuze:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="rblVierkant">Vierkant</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="rblKubus">Kubus</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Ander here is the code of the radiobuttons

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        keuze.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void rblObject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(rblObject.SelectedItem.Value == "rblVloer")
        {
            keuze.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: have you use `AutoPostBack=true` on radio list control?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some thing like this .I have done it by jQuery

```
 <script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#rblObject input').click(function () {
                var selectedValue = $("#rblObject input:radio:checked").val();
                alert('Selected Value: ' + selectedValue);
                if (selectedValue == "rblVloer") {

                $("#keuze").css({ display: "none" });
                } else {
                $("#keuze").css({ display: "" });
                }

            });

        });
    </script>
```

and

```
<div id="object" style="position:absolute; top:300px;">
        <label>Kies een object:</label>
        <br />
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblObject_SelectedIndexChanged"
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblObject" runat="server" Height="52px" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <asp:ListItem Value="rblVloer">Vloer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="rblKamer">Kamer</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="keuze" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top:400px;" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Maak je keuze:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="rblVierkant">Vierkant</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="rblKubus">Kubus</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Note: no need to postback

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

is necessary to get exact id of Control.

And make sure jQuery is loaded to perform this.